# Does Subsonic 3 ActiveRecord Handle Many To Many Relationships?

Tags: subsonic, subsonic3

Does the ActiveRecord template files create classes that handle many to many relationships?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will get an IQueryable foreign key reference object when the class is generated.

Comment: I assume in that instance, lets say ClassA has an IQueryable to ClassB that ClassB has a foreign key IQueryable to ClassC? That way you can return properties of ClassC when querying stuff in ClassA

Comment: That is correct.  I'd recommend downloading the latest bits and playing around.  It really only takes about 5 minutes to get up and running.  The docs are located here http://subsonicproject.com/docs/  and here is a great 5 minute demo screencast on getting started with subsonic3 http://subsonicproject.com/docs/The_5_Minute_Demo

Comment: Is there a naming convention for Many to Many tables?

Comment: No it sniffs out the foreign key references

Comment: I think this might be a new question but I'm trying to create a foreign key to the ASP.Net Membership Roles table but not sure how to query it as you don't have access to the GUID in the Membership Roles class

Comment: Yeah probably should be a new question.  For asp.net membership stuff probably better to just use builtin IsUserInRole stuff from System.Web.Security.Roles but Subsonic can handle this if you got the FKs setup.